# Named Credentials error: Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident

Tags: namedcredentials

I am trying to go through a OAUTH 2.0 Client Credentials flow.

When I try to hit a token url to get the bearer token using APEX everything goes smoothly. I tried to do the same setting up named credentials with the goal of storing the creds inside the external named credential but that gives me `Incapsula incident`.

Here's my APEX request which **works**:

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('https://some_endpoint.com/oauth2/v1/token');
req.setMethod('POST');
String username = 'someusername;
String password = 'somepassword';

req.setHeader('client_id', 'some_id');
req.setHeader('client_secret', 'some_secret');
req.setHeader('Accept', '*/*');
req.setHeader('content-type','application/json');
String requestBody = '{"username":"'+username+'","password": "'+password+'"}'; 
req.setBody(requestBody);

Http http = new Http();
HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
```

I tried setting up this in Named Credential and External Credentials, it looks like this:
[image]

In the external credential(which is set to Custom) I have set up the values for `username`, `password`, `client_id`, `client_secret` like so:
[image]

Then my APEX trying to leverage those configurations looks like this:

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('callout:Some_Named_Cred');
req.setMethod('POST');

req.setHeader('content-type','application/json');
req.setHeader('Accept', '*/*');
req.setHeader('client_id', '{!$Credential.Some_External_Cred.client_id}');
req.setHeader('client_secret', '{!$Credential.Some_External_Cred.client_secret}');
req.setHeader('content-type','application/json');
String requestBody = '{"username":"{!$Credential.Some_External_Cred.username}","password": "{!$Credential.Some_External_Cred.username}"}'; 
req.setBody(requestBody);

Http http = new Http();
HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
```

What I get is `Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 8223000510551812777-2200541552799845582`

Comment: Incapsula is a product SF is using in their implementation of this. Open a support case.